# Filter dataTables.net without included filter-box input

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to use the filter function of DataTables, but don't want to use their search box with it.

[In their docs](http://datatables.net/usage/features) under bFilter it says:

> Note that if you wish to use filtering in DataTables this must remain 'true' - to remove the default filtering input box and retain filtering abilities, please use

after which the sentence is left incomplete.

I tried:

```
var oTable = $('#sortable').dataTable({
    'bPaginate':false,
    'bInfo':false,
    'bFilter': true // displays Search box, setting false removes filter ability all together
});
$('#Accumulate').click(function(){
    oTable.fnFilter("Accumulate");
});
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can also hide is using css class

```
<style type="text/css">
.dataTables_filter {
     display: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Aha, simple and quick. Thanks.

Comment: sDom is also simple and quick. ;-) And it won't change CSS for other tables that could be using the search box. Definitely not "sour grapes" here, but I honestly feel that excluding the search box using the provided tools is a 'better' solution than including it then hiding it.

Comment: I'm not saying that my solution is better... Its just another solution , and as to the affect on other tables, it could be easily eliminated by providing a more "fine grained css selector" like #tableID dataTables_filter{...}

Comment: Oh, absolutely agree! Multiple options are always best. Just replying to Pratyush's comment, not judging this answer (which is perfectly valid).

Answer (score 13):

Pratyush,

Pure cosmetic showing and hiding of different UI elements is done with the sDom parameter:

http://datatables.net/usage/options#sDom

Note that the required syntax is different depending on if you're using jQuery UI or not.

Comment: I just looked at the sDom documentation and I would say it is far from "simple".  In fact, it made no sense to me.  Hiding via CSS is very simple and quick, albeit maybe not the optimal method.

Comment: Agreed; it's not simple. It took me more than a few attempts to get it right for my applications. However, I think the time invested in "getting it" pays off; you will then be able to modify the components instead of modifying the CSS.

Answer (score 13):

Use (potentially speed up datatable initialization as avoid some calculation):

```
$("#table").dataTable({"bFilter": false});
```

or any **sDom** without **f** option (refer to official docs http://datatables.net/usage/options#sDom for list of available options):

```
$("#table").dataTable({"sDom": '...t...'});
```

Look for same options at official support site: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/289/disable-search-filter-text-box

Answer (score 4):

```
"sDom": 'ltipr'
```

is the most simply of ways to do it.

full example that I have used:

```
 oTable = $('#overview').dataTable(

        {
           "aoColumns":[
                               null,
                               null,
                               null,
                               null,
                               null,
                                { "sSortDataType":"date-euro"},
                                { "sSortDataType":"date-euro",},
                               null
              ],
              "aaSorting":[],
              "iDisplayLength": -1,
              "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, -1], [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]],
              "sDom": 'ltipr'

        }
        );
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, I will try this, but I'm curious what 'ltipr' stands for, and if you could add some color to how this makes the filterbox hidden? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Poul, here is as follows:

'l' - Length changing
'f' - Filtering input 't' - The table!
'i' - Information
'p' - Pagination
'r' - pRocessing

if you leave our the f for example it will not show the filter