# yadcf plugin not filtering data

Tags: datatables, yadcf

I am loving this yadcf plugin an all its options.  But for some reason, I cannot get it to filter my data.  I want to type in data and have it filter on the fly.  I have looked through all the examples on the yadcf site and followed them to the best of my knowledge.  I am using JQuery 2.1.4, DataTables 1.10.10, and yadcf 0.8.9.beta.26.
Here is my relevant javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        'use strict';
        var table = $(".stocks").DataTable({
            paging: false,
            searching: false,
            info: false
        });

        yadcf.init(table, [
        {
            column_number : 4,
            filter_container_id: 'industrySearch',
            filter_default_label: "Type industry",
            filter_type: "text", 
            text_data_delimiter: ","
        }]);
```

Let me know if any other code is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must remove the `searching: false,` from your datatables init code.

Setting `searching` to `false` disables datatables searching abilities, and since yadcf uses datatables search api under the hood that it wont work.

[Read here more about this option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/searching#top)

Comment: Works perfect!  Thank you.  So if I don't actually want that search field, I just have to hide it manually with css or javascript?

Comment: You can take a look at my other answer related to it http://stackoverflow.com/a/9962171/617373 :)